# How to click an item within a frame and an iFrame with selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

What I'm trying to do is click this checkbox. However, it is in an iframe and a frame. I'm not sure how to select this. I continue to get an element not found. I've tried by ID, name, and Xpath.

HTML:

```
<iframe id="myframe" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 100%; position: absolute; height: 829px; display: block;" src="/f5-w-687474703a2f2f6e617973636c75737465722e6e63722e636f6d3a3830$$/MSL/jsp/MSLReDirect.jsp?ep=GIMV">
<frameset rows="100%,*" framespacing="false" frameborder="0" scrolling="No" noresize="" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" border="false">
<frame src="f5-h-$$/GIM/GIM?TARGET_PROCESSOR=com.ncr.gim.processor.OPFProcessor&amp;REQ=GIMA&amp;pageAccess=&amp;LAZ=Wed Mar 31 15:04:02 EDT 2021" name="GIMA" frameborder="0" border="0" scrolling="auto">
<input type="checkbox" id="StatusCheck" name="StatusCheck">
</frame>
</frameset>
</iframe>
```

My Script

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("frame"))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Advanced3"]/input[1]'))).sendkeys("test")
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Target the id myframe and then name GIMA and then id StatusCheck.

Comment: Did that with:
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("iframe"))
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name("GIMA"))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'StatusCheck')))
driver.switch_to.default_content()

Which still gives me the same error:
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: Id = myframe slightly off still.

Comment: Oops. Updated to driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("myframe")) and still got no element found